# Show that an elt. of the center of a group ring must be a sum of multiples of the group's conjugacy classes

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

This is part of a larger problem. The problem in full is: Let $\mathcal K_1,\cdots,\mathcal K_r$ be the conjugacy classes of a finite group $G$, and let $K_i$ be the sum of the members of $\mathcal K_i$ for each $i$. Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Prove that $\alpha$ is in the center of $RG$ if and only if $\alpha=a_1K_1+a_2K_2+\cdots+a_rK_r$ for some $a_1,\cdots,a_r\in R$.

I have already proven the $(\Leftarrow)$ direction; to do so, I showed that each $K_i$ is itself in the center of $RG.$ I'm a bit at a loss as to how to proceed for the $(\Rightarrow)$ direction, though.

Comment: Let $\alpha=\sum_{g\in G}r_gg$. Show that if $\alpha$ is in the center then you must have $r_g=r_{xgx^{-1}}$ for all $g,x\in G$.

Comment: Using this tip, I think I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is an attempt to follow through on Jyrki Lahtonen's tip in the comments.

Let $\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i g_i\in Z(RG)$, where $|G|=n$. Let $\beta\in RG$, $\beta=h\in G$. Then:
\begin{align*}
\alpha\beta=\beta\alpha &\implies \left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_ig_i \right)h = h\left(\sum_{i=1}^n r_ig_i \right)\\
&\implies \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\left(g_i h\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\left(hg_i \right)\\
&\implies \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\left(g_i h\right)h^{-1} = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\left(hg_i \right)h^{-1}\\
&\implies \sum_{i=1}^n r_i g_i = \sum_{i=1}^n r_i\left(hg_i h^{-1}\right)\\
\end{align*}
This shows that the coefficient of each $g$ in $G$ is invariant under conjugation of $g$ by any $h$ in $G$. This in turn shows that elements of the same conjugate class in $G$ must share the same coefficient, which is the desired result.